# The digits of the cube of a 3-digit number X

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, number-property

The digits of the cube of a certain 3-digit number X are, from left to right, the square of a 2-digit number, followed by the square of another 2-digit number, followed by one digit. (Everything is base 10.) What number is X?

Comment: This is a cute digit curiosity, but how is it a *puzzle*? Can anyone find a solution containing an "aha!" insight which enables you to find the answer without brute-forcing the cubes of all 3-digit integers until you find it?

Answer (score 5):

The number you're looking for is:

> 1,442,897

---

The three digit number $x$ is:

> 113

The two, two digit numbers ($y$ and $z$) are:

> $y = 12$ and $z = 17$; squared, these are $144$ and $289$ respectively.

The one digit number is:

> 7

Concatenating these together gives us:

> $x^3 = 1442897$

---

<sub>***Note**: I brute forced my answer since the [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag wasn’t specified.*</sub>

Comment: Could you note by what method you arrived at this answer? Trial and error?